# MVC4 ActionLink syntax for use with hidden text box values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the secret syntax for passing in two values from two hidden text boxes to a controller method?  I tried the syntax below but I get: CS0103: The name 'SearchLatitude' does not exist in the current context error message.  It doesn't see or like my hidden text box named SearchLatitude.  Not sure what to do, thank you.

```
@Html.ActionLink("SORT BY DISTANCE", "DisplayJobsDistance", "Job", new { Latitude = SearchLatitude, Longitude = SearchLongitude }, null)

<input type="hidden" name="SearchLatitude" id="SearchLatitude"> 
<input type="hidden" name="SearchLongitude" id="SearchLongitude">
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying.  The values in my hidden text boxes are put there after the page has loaded by a JavaScript function.  The values are not part of the model.

Comment: Can you post your controller Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ActionLink command won't work because it's looking for a property in the view called `SearchLatitude`. You need to add this to the Model that is passed to the view. If you don't know these values, maybe because they're added in the client be JavaScript, then some jQuery will help.

```
@Html.ActionLink("SORT BY DISTANCE", "DisplayJobsDistance", "Job", null, new {id="sortlink"})
```

and

```
$("#sortlink").click(function()
{
    var $lat = $("#SearchLatitude").val();
    var $lon = $("#SearchLongitude").val();

    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?latitude=" + $lat" + "&longitude=" + $lon);
}
```

Comment: I added 'var lat = Request.Params["lattitude"];' to use the parameter in my action method without having to change (or worry about) the Method's existing parameter list.

Comment: There is an error:$(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?latitude=" + $lat + "&longitude=" + $lon);

Answer (score 0):

I've used:

```
@model Person
@Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Id)
@Html.ActionLink("Person", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id })
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying.  The values in my hidden text boxes are put there after the page has loaded by a JavaScript function.  The values are not part of the model.

Comment: Can't you let the Javascript function inject the same values into your ActionLink?

Comment: The ActionLink generates an <a href="URL">Text</a>, just change the href in your JS.