# How to intercept ActionLink using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I want to add parameters to ActionLink from hidden field. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505894/mvc4-actionlink-syntax-for-use-with-hidden-text-box-values) answer that explains it, but it doesn't work for me, because it goes straight to controller action, without parsing jquery code.

```
 @Html.ActionLink(CommonResource.Delete, "PayrollPeriodDelete", "CodeTable", null, new { @id = "sortlink", @class = "btn btn-success" })

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('#PayrollPeriodSearch_FromDate').datepicker();
               
            $('#PayrollPeriodSearch_ToDate').datepicker();
        });
           
        $("#sortlink").click(function()
        {
            alert("works");
            var $lat = $("#hiddencode").val();
            $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?id=" + $lat);
        });

    </script>
```

I can tell my jquery works, because the above function runs just fine.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [jquery's "ready"](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to specify that your function must be executed when the DOM is fully loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#sortlink").click(function()
            {
                alert("works");
                var $lat = $("#hiddencode").val();
                $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?id=" + $lat);
            });

    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
$(document).on('click','#sortlink',function(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefualt(); // this will disable default action of action link...
    alert("works");
    var $lat = $("#hiddencode").val();
    window.location =  $(this).attr("href") + "?id=" + $lat;
});
```